# How to solve wave equation with discontinuous wave speed?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

I would like to solve the following equation
$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} - c^2(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}=0,$$
for $y=y(x,t)$ and $c(x,t)$ is of the form
$$c(x,t)=\begin{cases}
c_1(t), & x < 0 \\
c_2(t), & x \ge 0.
\end{cases}$$
The initial conditions are
$$y(x,0)=f(x),$$
$$\left.\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}=g(x).$$
The boundary conditions in $x$ are
$$y(-l, t)=y(l,t)=0.$$
If $c^2(x,t)$ were constant in $x$ I could convert this into a set of ODEs by assuming $y$ is of the form
$$y(x,t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty Y_n(t)\exp(ik_nx),$$
where
$$k_n = \frac{n \pi}{2l}.$$
Is there a way to convert this into a set of ODEs? Perhaps by using the Laplace transform? Any advice for approaching this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is $\color{red}+ c^{2}$ and not $\color{red}- c^{2}$ in the PDE? Also, you write 'if $c^{2}$ were constant in $x$ I could convert this into a set of ODEs'. Looking at the form of $c$ you gave for $x < 0$ and $x \ge 0$, it is clear that $c$ **is** constant in $x$ on each of the domains $(- l, 0)$ and $[0, l)$.

Comment: It should be $-c^2$, thanks. For $x\in[-l,0)$ and $x\in[0,l]$, $c$ is constant in $x$, however, both of the regions are coupled at $x=0$, since $y$ needs to be continuous. Are you saying I should solve each region separately? What would I use as boundary conditions at $x=0$?